# WCF Event Order

Tags: c#, wcf, deserialization

I need to hook into an event in a slightly unusual manner in WCF.

I'm passing a model from the client to the server, and I need access to that model:

1. After the model has been created *but*
2. Before the incoming data has actually been deserialized to that model

The reason is I actually have deserialization events that are conditional, and ideally I want that condition itself to be a property on the object; thus, I'd have the pattern:

> create object->set property->deserialize the rest of the object based
>   on that property

Is there an event in WCF that I can hook into for this? I've got an attribute set up that hooks into the "IOperationBehavior" and "IParameterInspector" set up, but those don't (as far as I can tell) have an action that hooks in between the creation and deserialization events.

Alternatively, I'd be fine with a way of modifying the data coming in off the wire and explicitly adding that property into the incoming data, provided I could guarantee that it would be the first property deserialized.

Any ideas?

[Edit]
Minor note, I'm using JSON as the data transport here, not that that should really have an impact on the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically implement a nested envelope, whereby the actual data passed to your WCF service consists of a class (the envelope) which has the data needed to determine how to deserialize and a byte array which consists of the real data in a serialized format.  Then you could manage the deserialization of the byte array manually.

Seems there is probably a better way, but I've done similar things and they work.

EDIT: Perhaps an [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) is the right place to hook?

Comment: That looks interesting...I can probably pre-parse it, add my property, and then re-serialize it...